# Datasnap and TObject references

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

How to handle object references in datasnap server?

I have Datasnap server method which returns TUser object

```
TServerMethods.CurrentUser(const AId: Integer): TUser
begin
  Result := GlobalCurrentUser; // <- Don't want to free this object
  Result.AddReference;
end;
```

TUser in child class of TReferencedObject

```
TReferencedObject = class(TObject)
private
  FReferenceCnt:     integer;
public
  procedure AddReference; virtual;
  procedure RemoveReference; virtual; // Frees object if reference count goes to 0
  property ReferenceCnt: integer Read FReferenceCnt Write FReferenceCnt;
end;
```

Currently DataSnap server Frees TUser object but I want to call RemoveReference for TReferencedObject descendants.

Answer (score 1):

I copied DataSnap files Data.DBXJSONReflect.pas and Datasnap.DSReflect.pas to project directory, add to project and made three modifications.

Two changes in Data.DBXJSONReflect to set correct ReferenceCount

1) TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject

```
  if HasObject(ObjId) then
  begin
    Obj := GetObject(ObjId);
    if Obj is TReferencedObject then {Framework}
      TReferencedObject(Obj).AddReference; {Framework}    
    exit(Obj);
  end
```

2) TJSONPopulationCustomiser.PostPopulate

```
  if Data is TReferencedObject then {Framework}
    TReferencedObject(Data).AddReference; {Framework}
```

One change in Datasnap.DSReflect to release reference

1) TDsMethodValues.ClearReferenceParameters

changed **FUserObject.Clear** to **ClearUserObjects(FUserObjects);** and added local function

```
  procedure ClearUserObjects(const AUserObjects: TObjectList<TObject>); {Framework}
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    FUserObjects.OwnsObjects := False;
    for i := FUserObjects.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      if FUserObjects.Items[i] is TReferencedObject then
      begin
        TReferencedObject(FUserObjects.Items[i]).RemoveReference;
        FUserObjects.Delete(i);
      end;
    FUserObjects.OwnsObjects := True;
    FUserObjects.Clear;
  end;
```